# Are there any recommended texts that cover Turing Tilings?

Tags: lo.logic, textbook-recommendation, tiling

I have read the original paper by Wang, as well as a paper by Boas [1996] entitled 'the Convenience of Tilings', but wanted to know if there were any other texts that people could recommend that include sections on Turing Tilings?

Secondarily to this, I would very much like to hear of any attempts to include Oracle computations in Turing Tilings...

Comment: The Wikipedia page has a number of references and a good discussion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile